# Remove listener from Firebase when having multiple listeners on the same reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I needed to listen to a reference on firebase realtime database that will be updated very often, so I tried to encapsulate the listeners in a component in a way that, if the components were not viewable by the user, the listeners would be turned off.

I created a high order component to avoid leaking listeners that looks like this:

```
const FirebaseListener = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            ref: null,
            data: {},
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            const { device } = this.props;

            const ref = repository.listenDevice(device.id);
            ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.val();
                this.setState({ data });
            });

            ref.on('child_changed', (snapshot) => {
                const value = snapshot.val();
                const prop = snapshot.key;
                const { data } = this.state;
                this.setState({ data: { ...data, [prop]: value } });
            });
            this.setState({ ref });
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            const { ref } = this.state;
            if (ref !== null) {
                ref.off();
            }
        }

        render() {
            const { data } = this.state;
            return (
                <WrappedComponent data={data} {...this.props} />
            );
        }
    };
};
```

But in the way I structured the app, I ended up making two listeners on the same reference and when I call `ref.off()`, I lose both of the listeners which is not the intended behavior.

It happens like this:

```
1. already          2. push configview into stack   3. has another
has listener        and adds another listener       listener
------------             ------>                 --------------
|           |                                    |             |
|           |                                    |             |
| listview  |                                    |  configview |
|  screen   |                                    |   screen    |
|           |                                    |             |
-------------            <-------                ---------------
5. doesn't have           4. pops configview from stack
listener anymore       and removes both listeners
```

*Basically, is there any way to remove only a specific listener from a reference on firebase?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can precisely control what listener(s) gets removed. The key here is that you need to have a reference to the callback function. With anonymous function declarations, you can get that reference as the return value from `on()`:

```
let listener = ref.on('child_changed', (snapshot) => {
    const value = snapshot.val();
    const prop = snapshot.key;
    const { data } = this.state;
    this.setState({ data: { ...data, [prop]: value } });
});
```

Then later you can remove that listener with:

```
ref.off('child_changed', listener);
```

Also see the reference documentation of [`on`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) and [`off`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#off).